# Return PHP object by index number (not name)

Tags: php, object

Goal: retrieve an element of data from within a PHP object by number.

This is the print_r($data) of the object:

```
stdClass Object
(
    [0] => stdClass Object
        (
            [TheKey] => 1456
            [ThingName] => Malibu
            [ThingID] => 7037
            [MemberOf] => California
            [ListID] => 7035
            [UserID] => 157
            [UserName] => John Doe
        )
)
```

I can't figure out how to pull a value out of it. This is only one record of a multi-record object that should be by id rather than a name.

These are some failed attempts to illustrate what the goal is:

```
echo $data -> 0 -> UserName;
echo $data[0] -> UserName;
```

Answer (score 39, accepted):

Normally, PHP variable names can't start with a digit. You can't access `$data` as an array either as `stdClass` does not implement `ArrayAccess` — it's just a normal base class.

However, in cases like this you can try accessing the object attribute by its numeric name like so:

```
echo $data->{'0'}->UserName;
```

The only reason I can think of why Spudley's answer would cause an error is because you're running PHP 4, which doesn't support using `foreach` to iterate objects.

Comment: Are you sure that works? On PHP 5.3, it yields `Undefined property: stdClass::$0`, which is what my experience has always been.

Comment: @konforce: I think my suggestion works on PHP 4, which would be what I assume OP is running since Spudley's answer doesn't work.

Comment: In that case, I'd add something like `if (version_compare(PHP_VERSION, '5.0.0', '>=')) die('PHP 5 is not supported');` or at least a big warning as a comment that the code is not forward compatible.

Comment: It's undefined whether this works. The properties shouldn't exist; it's probably come from converting an array to an object, and you shouldn't try to access numerically-indexed properties in such an object.

Answer (score 8):

BoltClock's suggestion to use "$data->{'0'}->UserName" apparently no longer works with PHP 5.

I had the same problem and I found that current() will work to get that numbered class element like this...

```
echo current($data)->UserName;
```

Or if that doesn't work (depending on the object) you may need to do another current() call like this:

```
echo current(current($data))->UserName;
```

Answer (score 4):

this works for PHP5+

```
echo $data[0]->UserName;
```

or

```
foreach ($data as $data){
    echo $data->UserName;
    }
```

or as suggested by @orrd

```
current($data)->UserName works great too.
```

Comment: I an thinking why this answer didn't get green check

Answer (score 3):

Have you tried a `foreach()` loop? That should give you all the accessible elements, and the
keys it returns may give you a better clue as to how to access them directly.

Comment: <b>Fatal error</b>:  Cannot use object of type stdClass as array

Comment: what version of PHP are you using? As of PHP5, you should be able to use `foreach` on an object. (if you're still using PHP4, you should upgrade as it's been end-of-life for over two years)

Comment: +1 as this would have worked on supported versions of PHP anyway. Definitely looks like a PHP 4 case here.

Answer (score 0):

<del>try this:</del>

```
echo $data[0]['UserName'];
```

According to the manual, objects are not meant to be used that way. The comments [on this page](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.iterations.php) do provide a way around if that's a must-have for you. You could also simply rely on arrays if you are just using the object for properties (and not behaviours).

Comment: <b>Fatal error</b>:  Cannot use object of type stdClass as array in <b>file.php</b> on line <b>44</b><br />

Comment: i updated my answer. In short, i don't think that is possible out of the box but it can be implemented.