# Getting stdclass and array values in PHP

Tags: php, arrays, stdclass

How do I access the following stdclass, and echo Transaction ID has already been used.

```
object(stdClass)#2 (1) {
  ["SendBulkSMS_PHPResult"]=>
  object(stdClass)#3 (1) {
    ["string"]=>
    array(3) {
      [0]=>
      string(1) "0"
      [1]=>
      string(37) "Transaction ID has already been used."
      [2]=>
      NULL
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: This might help you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3851489/return-php-object-by-index-number-not-name

Answer (score 0):

From the look of it, it would be:

```
$object->SendBulkSMS_PHPResult->string[1];
```

Comment: it does not work if tried above line, whereas doing $response->SendBulkSMS_PHPResult->string[1]; helped and returned the actual value from the stdclass

Comment: Thanks :-) anyways it helped.