# What exactly does $object->{0} do?

Tags: php

I've seen in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26734455/4858808) the code

```
$tmpNode = parent::addChild($name,null,$namespace);
$tmpNode->{0} = $value;
```

I'm curious what the `->{0}` actually does? Which PHP language construct is this? Does it reference the first property of `$tmpNode` without using its name?

## Update:

I've seen the answers given so far, but I was looking for a reference into the PHP language manual that explains this use of curly braces. When I search in the [PHP Manual](http://php.net/manual/en) for `curly` the only hit is to the [page about strings](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php) where curly's are only explained in the context of variables and complex expressions. It wasn't clear to me that the language allows curly's around literals.

Comment: var_dump($tmpNode); u will get all the answers.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3851489/return-php-object-by-index-number-not-name

Comment: Take a look at: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10333016/how-to-access-object-properties-with-names-like-integers

Comment: Thanks, @mapek, your link shows how complex this topic really is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Curly brackets `{}` in [php](/questions/tagged/php) are also used to parse complex codes. Take this for example:

```
$t = 0;

$$t = 5;

echo ${0}; //outputs 5
```

or this:

```
${0} = 65;

echo ${0}; //outputs 65
```

but if  you were to try this:

```
$0 = 65;

echo $0;
```

you would get:

> Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '0' (T_LNUMBER), expecting variable (T_VARIABLE) or '$'

It is the same with object properties:

```
$obj = new stdClass();

$obj->{1} = "Hello world";
echo $obj->{1}; //outputs "Hello world"
```

[Complex (curly) syntax](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.parsing.complex)