# Undefined property: stdClass:: codeigniter 3 with php 5.3.6

Tags: php, codeigniter

I'm using codeigniter 3 with php 5.3.6 and I get this error when trying to echo $row[0]->ACOM;

```
Message: Undefined property: stdClass::$ACOM
```

var_dump

```
var_dump($row[0]);
object(stdClass)#22 (1) { ["ACOM"]=> string(11) "43000005370" }
```

Print_R

```
print_r($row[0]);
stdClass Object ( [ACOM] => 43000005370 )
```

echo

```
echo $row[0]->ACOM;
Message: Undefined property: stdClass::$ACOM
```

I can work with arrays if I return a result_array();

```
echo $row[0]['ACOM'];
```

shows `43000005370`

But I don't know what's going on with objects...

edit:

My model:

```
<?php
defined('BASEPATH') OR exit('No direct script access allowed');

class Menu_model extends CI_MODEL
{   
    public function menuJoin($atec)
        {   
            $this->db->select('ACOM');
            $this->db->from(LIBRERIA1.'.AVSSAT');
            $this->db->where('ATEC',$atec);

            $query = $this->db->get();

            //return $query->result_array();
            return $query->result();
        }
}
```

My controller:

```
<?php
defined('BASEPATH') OR exit('No direct script access allowed');

class Menu extends CI_Controller
{

    public function __construct()
        {
            parent::__construct();

        }

    public function index()
        {    
            $this->load->model('Menu_model');
            $datos=$this->Menu_model->menuJoin($_SESSION['MWCOME']);

            $this->load->view("comun/head");
            $this->load->view("menu/header_menu");
            $this->load->view("menu/menu", array( "row" =>  $datos) );
            $this->load->view("comun/footer");
        }
}
```

My view:

```
<?php
var_dump($row[0]);
echo $row[0]->ACOM;
?>
```

Thanks for your help

Comment: what do you get when you `var_dump($row);`

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3851489/return-php-object-by-index-number-not-name may be releated

Comment: Try this  `echo $row[0]->{ACOM};`

Comment: Try this echo $row[0]->ACOM;

Comment: show us your controller and model code.

Comment: edited with my model and controller... still got the same error when echo $row[0]->ACOM;

Answer (score 0):

have you tried $row[0]->ACOM; ?

```
the row[0] is a object based on 

print_r($row[0]);
stdClass Object ( [ACOM] => 43000005370 )
```

so $row[0]->ACOM will work.

Comment: Yes, I've tried and the error is the same "error Message: Undefined property: stdClass::$ACOM"